# How to deal with the intercept when doing PCR manually in R

Tags: r, regression, pca

I am trying to compute PCR manually in R where I try to compute the principal components for the train data then compute the coefficients from these data and use it to predict the test data. The problem I'm facing is that the size of the intercept will have the same size as the training data so I am confused as to how I could perform a prediction on test data that has a different size.

To compute the PCR manually I used the following formula

$$ y=Z\theta+\epsilon $$

and $ Z= XV $, where  $X$ is our data matrix and $V$ are the loadings from the PCA (principal component analysis), $\epsilon$ is our intercept and $\theta$ contains the regreession coefficients and can be computed like this
$$ \theta =(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^Ty $$

I used this knowledge to perform the computations in R

```
train.pca <- princomp(train[, -2]) #remove response
X <- train.pca$scores
V <- train.pca$loadings[, -15] # using 14 components
Z <- X %*% V

theta <- solve(t(Z) %*% Z) %*% t(Z) %*% train$y
Y_hat <- Z %*% theta
epsilon <- Y_hat - train$y

#Compute test data predictions

test.pca <- princomp(test[, -2])
X.test <- test.pca$scores
V.test <- test.pca$loadings[, -15]
Z.test <- X.test %*% V.test

pred.test <- Z.test %*% theta + epsilon # here would be the problem

# epsilon size is the same as train
# Z.test * theta size is the same as test (test.size < train.size)
```

The multiplication of `Z.test %*% theta` computes a matrix of size `test` whereas `epsilon` is of size `train`. How can I overcome this

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What happens if you add a column of $1$s to your $Z$ matrix before you do the $(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^Ty?$

Comment: @Dave Hi! Can you please explain to me why the column of 1s is needed here? We are not using X as a direct input for the regression but rather Z which transforms X with the desired number of principal components. Had we used X as a direct input then we could add the 1s

Comment: When you do the usual $\hat\beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ for a model matrix $X$, it is typical (though not mandatory) to have a column of all $1$s to allow for an intercept term, in addition to your feature columns. When you make your new model matrix, you might consider adding a column of $1$s in addition to the new features generated by the PCA. This will be totally analogous to the usual estimate.

Comment: @Dave I tried adding the 1s to a new array `ny` and also for the test data `ny.test`  but now I get an error `Error in ny.test %*% theta.ny + epsilon : non-conformable arrays`

Comment: @Dave If I remove the `epsilon` I obviously don't get the error but now the RMSE is too high when compared to computing the RMSE from PCR with the library(pls). My RMSE from manual PCR is 1.525... and from the library(pls) 0.353 when using the same number of components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. The problem was that I was using the loadings of the test data to compute the Z matrix instead of the loadings of the training data which makes no sense. Also for the data matrix I need to use the actual data and not the scores.

````
train.pca <- princomp(train[, -2]) #remove response
X <- train[, -2]
V <- train.pca$loadings[, -15] # using 14 components
Z <- X %*% V

theta <- solve(t(Z) %*% Z) %*% t(Z) %*% train$y
Y_hat <- Z %*% theta

#Compute test data predictions

test.pca <- princomp(test[, -2])
X.test <- test[, -2]
Z.test <- X.test %*% V

pred.test <- Z.test %*% theta

```
````